# How to handle multiple API calls in single component in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-redux

I have react native parent component which contain 4 child components. Each child component need the web service data from different API's. If I call the web service, the parent component render 4 times. How to handle this situation and render the particular child component when the API get the responses ?

Comment: you can use purecomponent(class component) or memo(functional component)

Comment: Can you please suggest any example code for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [hooks api](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html), there's a variety of hooks like useMemo or useEffect that can achieve exactly what you are looking for

Comment: Can you please add any code snippet or example link ?